# Executing `make` inside multiple directories

Tags: shell, find

I am trying to run `make` command inside multiple folders which start with `g-`. How can I do so?

I was wondering if I could use "find" command to solve it. Can you help me to understand it better?

I tried:

```
find . -type d -name "g-*"  -exec make {}\;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke `make` with the `-C` option.

```
find . -type d -name 'g-*' -exec make -C {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your attempt, I conclude that each `g-` directory contains a suitable `Makefile`. Hence you can do a

```
 find . -type d -name 'g-*'  -exec sh -c 'cd {}; make' \;
```

Comment: @oguzismail : Ah, you are right! We would have to search for `Makefile` instead, but this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: I fixed it. While for the problem at hand, your solution with `-C` is much more elegant preferable here, I think the idea to do the `cd` explicitly as part of the `-exec` is more general. I didn't know about `-C` because the last times I was working with a _make_ was always with `clearmake` (part of the Clearcase version control system), which does not support such an option.

Comment: @oguzismail : The only risk I see is that you may chdir into a directory, where you can't legally come back, but `make -C` faces the same problem. I'm surprised that there would be a platform, where `-exec` does not support it. At least BSD, AIX and Solaris  `find` have it, so I wonder where I could run into trouble with this.

Comment: A non-empty `CDPATH` in the environment may affect the behavior of `cd` unless the starting point has dot or dot-dot as the first character. The standard allows but doesn't mandate any `{}` to be substituted, and there's no change on that in 202x draft, that's why I deem it unreliable.

Comment: @oguzismail : Interesting point. I tried to fix my solution to protect against CDPATH, by using `sh` instead of `bash`, but a quick check with my `sh` showed that it also honours CDPATH. `ash` or `dash` would work, but we can't assume that they are available. I also verified that the POSIX standard indeed defines {} only a single, final argument. Given that we also can't rely on `make` accepting `-C`, because of the many varieties beign around, I wonder what's really a foolproof way to accomplish the goal....

Comment: Well, you can do `-exec sh -c 'CDPATH= cd "$1"; make' _ {} \;` I guess.